# How to automatically call a php script every day to send out automatic emails

Tags: php, mysql, cron, cron-task

Is there a way where I can automatically call a php script after a specified interval.

I have a php script(say remindusers.php) that uses mysql to query a database where people have submitted their weekly reports. This script automatically queries the database and sends an email reminder to people who have not sent in their weekly reports yet.

What I am now supposed to do is give the ADMIN an option to set a reminder start and reminder end date during which calls should be automatically made to my remindusers.php script and cease on reminder end date.

What I learnt from SO/google is that I can setup cron (in LINUX) to automatically call my remindusers.php, but I dont have any shell access to do this.

Else Can I write another php script to essentially sleep every 24 hours and automatically wake up to call my remindusers.php script.

Are there any other built-in methods ?

Any ideas?

Comment: I would contact your web host to find out if you can set up crons anyways.  I think needing cron jobs is a pretty common request, so many hosts would have some way to set them up, even without shell access.

Comment: what hosting type do you have, even with out shell, a lot of hosts offer cron jobs via cpanel

Comment: Say even if i set up cron access, can it save the data from my index.php(my website) and issue queries with the same data every 24 hours?

Comment: yes it can...... well cron does nothing but run the script, its up to the script to do all the heavy lifting

Comment: If you have access to a scheduler on another machine that is up and running (not like a desktop you shutdown every night), you can create a task to call your remindusers.php script on an interval, checking if it's run in the last 24 hours and running if not. I wouldn't use `sleep()` since I would think that would lock up resources to that script.

Answer (score 1):

Use your site's visitors to trigger the event. Send a message and then check if 1 day elapsed. Then send another. You still need to pay attention not to double/triple/... send deu to synchronization.

When the time has elapsed use a MySQL (or system) MUTEX to ensure only one send occurs.

Comment: What if there are no visitors?

Comment: @PSN Tough luck. Use a system cronjob. Or trigger a visit from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! What you need to do is to use cron jobs. Cron jobs are essentially telling the server to execute a script (PHP or otherwise) at regular intervals. Cron jobs are very powerful and customizable, as you can set virtually any interval for your cron.

If you are using CPanel to manage your site, there is a button in CPanel to view all the cron jobs you have set. There is also a tutorial on that page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dagon Actually yes. He was asking about how to set up a cron job and I actually gave an answer on how to do it, rather than just tell him that he should use crons. Where's your answer?

Comment: Forgive me if i ask a trivial question. As i understand, cron simply calls a script at specified intervals. My remindusers.php needs data from a form from my webpage. Based on that data it issues queries. Can the cron save this data and pass onto my script at regular intervals. ALso, I will have to automate the cron to start and end whenever the ADMIN wants. and typically the admin will enter this data to my webpage form.

Comment: @PSN - You create a table that accepts the form data you're talking about; when it's submitted, push it into your table, and then the cron task runs the script that reads the data from your table and does what it says. cron does not specifically accept data from anywhere; it's only a way to automate a script being run, based on some task (this is why it's called a Scheduled Task in Windows).

Comment: If you want, you can have your script that processes form input save that data to a file, and then the scheduled script just accesses the data in the file. As for begin and end, the cron can check and only execute if the current time is between the begin and end date that the ADMIN entered, which would be in the file. You could also store the data in MySQL if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @RamsaySmith..Nice idea. Let me implement that and check. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this PHPCron

PHPCron is a simple PHP script which lets you run multiple tasks on a schedule or timer. It can be run either from the command-line or via a web browser. Its behaviour is very similar to the popular cron program for UNIX.

http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2006/10/17/phpcron-running-scheduled-tasks-from-php-on-a-web-server/

Comment: @esbedon I will have a look into your answer later and check if that works.:-)

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you don't have Shell access but have you had a look at the cPanel to see whether there is an option to setup a cron job in there?

Comment: comment, not an answer

Comment: well i can't "comment" as i don't have enough reputation to do so

Comment: Guys, I have no shell, no cpanel whatsoever. I cannot need any external application to do my work, since the IT requires to be notified when I need to download cpanel, which I do not want. My code will be shipped to a customer. You typically dont need the customer to have cpanel.

Comment: php has no internal scheduling you have to rely on an outside source, or you simply cant do this

Comment: @Dagon I think ramsay smith's answer makes sense, but he too needs cron to do it.:-(

Comment: When someone submits their weekly report can you not make the script check whether everyone else has done so and send an email to anyone who hasn't done so within the set time frame?

ie. I submit my report... whilst accepting the report the script also checks to see if others have submitted their report and if not sends them an email.

Comment: @Atzaman.. Yes. infact that was the first thing i had implemented. But alas, we need a specific ADMIN reminder tab to send reminders which the ADMIN can have control over. I mean, ADMIN wants to have control over when the reminders start and end.

Comment: A little tricky without cron... I guess another solution would be to store the ADMIN reminder settings in the database and just have the reminder script run the first time someone logs into the system each day.